# Autostart youtube live event

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I try to make a oneclick solution to start a youtube broadcast live-event with PHP. I have manage to create a live event at a specific time.
But I have to go to the youtube control room to first preview my stream and then start it.
What I want is to get the livestream to start broadcast automaticly when the time is set and not have to interact with youtube control room.

Is this possible to manage this with the youtube-api and PHP?

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to automatically start a live stream after binding your `liveStream` and `liveBroadcast` objects. After binding your `liveStream` to your `liveBroadcast`, you have the opportunity to test the quality and connection of your stream and debug your encoder in YouTube’s Control Room.  After testing, or if you just want to go live, you transition your `liveBroadcast` from the active to the live state.  This can be one of the bigger bottlenecks of your application, as the broadcast state transition can take up to a minute to transition to live.  I just kept polling the `liveStreams` endpoint with my live stream id id until `streamStatus` returned `active`.

Comment: arg.. I wish there was a better way to do it. Btw, what do you do if your encoder application breaks during the streaming, and you never got the chance to tell youtube that the stream is over? apparently it keeps streaming garbage until you manually change the state. Any Suggestions for this ?

Comment: @omarojo you should ask a new question.